# Which characters Midoriya inspired his techniques from?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In the anime, mainly in the 3rd season, Midoriya mentions some characters he inspired his techniques from,

- The punching style of attacking he copied it from All Might, this is mentioned by All Might himself.
- He tells he developed full cowling inspired in Gran Torino and Kacchan attacks.
- He asked Iida for help to develop his kicking technique.

As we know Midoriya analizes all the heroes and he writes notes about them. Is there any other characters he inspired his techniques and attacks from?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would like to add more on that list but that's all. It's true that he observes and takes note but as for now he is still trying to improve Full Cowling.

Answer (score -1):

Well as of now, i think that he is focusing more on his more used techniques such as full cowling, considering that he has taken inspiration from his fellow classmates, theres a possibility that he will learn new moves, currently for the anime anyway.